# Сводная таблица в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Товарищи, добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно посчитать количество строк в документе `CSV` через метод `pivot_table`?

И ещё один момент, как выгрузить пустые значения?
Делаю:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=';')
df.head()
count_severity = df.pivot_table(index="Base", values="ID", aggfunc="count", margins=True, dropna=False)
print(count_severity)
```

получаю:

| Base | ID |
| --- | --- |
| CRITICAL | 6 |
| HIGH | 62 |
| MEDIUM | 36 |
| All | 109 |

но, если открыть в Excel через сводную таблицу, то:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видно,  что есть пустые значения.

большое спасибо.

Comment: Навскидку можно попробовать параметр `dropna=True`, а вообще приведите исходные данные и ваш код их чтения в `dataframe`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, привёл полный текст кода. Попробовал так: `count_severity = df.pivot_table(index=["Base"], values="ID", aggfunc="count", dropna=True)` - результат тот же

Comment: Тьфу т.е. наоборот, конечно, нужно попробовать `dropna=False`, а `True` это у него по умолчанию значение.

Comment: Пробовал, кажется, что `dropna` работает только с методом  `groupby`, а не `pivot_table`

Comment: Добавил параметры `margins=True, dropna=False` появилась строка где указано количество строк в файле, но опять же, не отображается пустые значения.

Comment: Ну тогда только сам файл предосталять, без данных непонятно как и что тут советовать

Comment: а что не понятно? есть файл `CSV`, в нём 2 столбца `ID` и `Base`. Столбец `ID` имеет числовые значения, они все разные и все ячейки заполнены. Столбец `Base` имеет только некоторые данные `CRITICAL`, `HIGH`, `MEDIUM`, `LOW`, бывает что не все ячейки заполнены... вот и всё

Comment: Я пошёл немного другим путём, не знаю, верно или нет, но при чтении файла пустые строки заменяю на какое-либо значение: `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=";", encoding="utf-8").fillna("Пустые")` таким образом в файл ни какие изменения не вносятся и в программе отображается всё как надо..

Comment: Ну, если так работает, то и ладно